# websocketspp/websockets++ want to store a handler passed as parameter

Tags: c++, websocket

I'm need help with websocketspp / websockets++ please (https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp).

I'm open to other simpler libraries, also C, if that's an overall better option :)

My overall goal is to have a websockets webpage as a replacement for a telnet client for DikuMUD.

I've been using the "echo_server" example which is running fine.

I'm trying to save the connection handler "hdl" from one callback and then re-use it later to send another message back to the client. Looks to me like hdl is a class that will get created / destroyed on the stack with each function call to e.g. on_message.

I would like to store the hdl somehow, e.g. in a std::map so that I can look it up and use that looked up hdl to send another message later to the same client.

Here's the example. Sorry for the void , I'm used to C and lightweight C++ :)

```
std::map<void *, void *> g_cMapHandler;

// Define a callback to handle incoming messages
void on_message(server* s, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg)
{
    void *myExample = 0; // A value I need to be able to retrieve 

    // Using &hdl here doesn't make sense, I presume hdl gets destroyed when on_message ends.
    g_cMapHandler[&hdl] = myExample;

    // But I can't figure out what really represents hdl? Maybe there a fd / file descriptor
    // I can store somehow, and then how do I rebuild a hdl from it?
}
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connection_hdl` is istelf a pointer, store `connection_hdl`. It is a weak pointer.

Generally, suggest avoiding `void*` with asio, and using reference-counted smart pointers. Even though you can control lifetime of object in a synchronous program, and call `free` or `delete` when needed, in asynchronous program the flow is varying, so the right place to free pointer could be different place each time.

asio may use `boost::weak_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr`. `boost` one has `operator <`, so can be directly used in a map. For `std`, there's `std::weak_ptr<T>::owner_before` to be used for ordering, can be used via `std::owner_less`

```
std::map<websocketpp::connection_hdl, void *, std::owner_less<websocketpp::connection_hdl>> g_cMapHandler;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, awesome, that last example saved me :-)  Would never have figured that out. Need to go look at a C++ tutorial now ;)